# Configure auto updates for extension in chromium linux

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, chromium

Is there a way to disable auto updates on Chromium extensions?

I do not see this in:

1. ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
2. /etc/chromium/master_preferences
3. man chromium

Seems like there should be a simple runtime option like `about:config` in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This subject is treated in the post
[How to disable Google Chrome extension autoupdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657617/how-to-disable-google-chrome-extension-autoupdate).

As you seem to be on linux, here is the summary of one
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67698984/165358).
If it helps you, please also upvote that answer.

**Disabling update for a specific extension**

We use system policies on Linux :

- Get the installed extensions list (IDs), this can be found with
  `ls -l ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions` or
  `chrome://extensions`
- Create the necessary directory if not present:
  `sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed`
- Create the needed file policies file:
  `touch /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/google-chrome.json`
- Edit the file with :

  ```
  {
        "ExtensionSettings": {
          "ghijklmnopabcdefghijklmnopabcdef": {
            "update_url": "https://127.0.0.1/update_url",
        "override_update_url": true
          },
          "YOUR-EXTENSION-ID-LIKE-THE-PREVIOUS-EXAMPLE": {
            "update_url": "https://127.0.0.1/update_url",
            "override_update_url": true
          }
        }
      }
  ```
- Open `chrome://policy/` and reload the policies.